# Erro ao compilar pacote R 4.1 no linux baseado em Debian

Tags: r, compilação, linux

Estou tentando instalar/compilar o software R-project, não venho obtendo sucesso. Distro linux baseada em Debian.

Seguem os passos que realizei:

**1-** Baixei o pacote R-4.1.1.tar.gz  no link: https://cran.r-project.org/

**2-** descompactei com o comando : `tar -zxvf R-4.1.1.tar.gz`

**3-** li os arquivos README e INSTALL

**4-** segui os comandos indicados pelo arquivo INSTALL

**5-** primeiro comando: `./configure`

onde neste comando  aparece o seguinte :

````
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
loading site script './config.site'
loading build-specific script './config.site'
checking for pwd... /usr/bin/pwd
checking whether builddir is srcdir... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for ar... ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for which... /usr/bin/which
checking for less... /usr/bin/less
checking for gtar... no
checking for gnutar... no
checking for tar... /usr/bin/tar
checking for tex... no
checking for pdftex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals
checking for pdflatex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
checking for makeindex... no
checking for texi2any... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
checking for texi2dvi... no
checking for kpsewhich... no
checking for latex inconsolata package... checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
checking for gzip... /usr/bin/gzip
checking for bzip2... /usr/bin/bzip2
checking for firefox... /usr/bin/firefox
using default browser ... /usr/bin/firefox
checking for acroread... no
checking for acroread4... no
checking for xdg-open... /usr/bin/xdg-open
checking for working aclocal... missing
checking for working autoconf... missing
checking for working autoheader... missing
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for yacc... no
checking for notangle... false
checking for realpath... /usr/bin/realpath
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
looking for a modern Fortran compiler
checking for gfortran... no
checking for g95... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for ifort... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgfortran... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for ftn... no
checking for nagfor... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for f90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for g77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for f77... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for cf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
configure: error: No Fortran compiler found ```
````

**6-** já atentei os seguintes comandos:

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
./configure –prefix=/usr/local –with-slang=/goodies/lib
```

**7-** nada resolveu

Comment: Olá @Ulysses, eu não vou conseguir te ajudar, pois não uso R nem nunca tentei compilar ele. Porém acessando o link que você postou achei isso https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/ . Para tentar ajudar você a clarificar mais sua pergunta para a comunidade entender seu problema. **Você tentou instalar pelo meio tradicional (`apt`) ?** - **Existe algum motivo para você querer baixar e compilar ?** - **quanto ao erro mostrado `configure: error: No Fortran compiler found` você tentou fazer algo ?**

Comment: Se precisa da versão mais recente do R, a melhor maneira é por APT, usando repositório *backport* (veja as instruções específicas para sua versão do Debian no link postado pelo Icaro). Se é uma distro baseada em Debian, verifique primeiro se ela disponibiliza um sistema de backport e se o R está nele.

Comment: Pelo método tradicional tentei sim, segui o que tem na página oficial. Mas é que tem distros baseada em debian( POP OS) que vem com a versao 3.6, e na minha atual distro (AMAROK) esta vindo com o 4.0 (aplicando os comandos "tradicionais"  **apt**) 
Mas no site oficial já tem um pacote em **tar .gz** com a última versão, somente é uma instalação diferente, ou seja, a compilação.  E que onde esse pacote não funciona  os comandos recomendados pelo README e INSTALL.

Comment: Mas vou verificar se há algo faltando em minha distro, e também verificar as backport. 
E quanto ao erro do “fortran”, estou na procura. Mas sem sucesso por enquanto.

Muito obrigado! Pelas dicas !!!

Answer (score 3):

Comece por editar o ficheiro de reporitórios para o R versão 4.*, veja a documentação oficial em [Debian Packages of R Software](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/'
```

Ou, manualmente, edite o ficheiro

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

e inclua a linha

```
deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/
```

Ou, em Ubuntu, no ficheiro

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

inclua as linhas

```
deb https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/
deb-src https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/
```

Agora deverá ser só atualizar e instalar

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base r-base-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá no próprio FAQ tem alguns passos :

> Debian packages, maintained by Dirk Eddelbuettel, have long been part
> of the Debian distribution, and can be accessed through APT, the
> Debian package maintenance tool.

// Traduzindo ficaria que o pacotes de dependencia do R não vem como padrao no Debian e pode ser instaldo por esses comandos:

```
apt-get install r-base r-recommended

apt-get install r-base-dev
```

Comment: sim , mas não é a versão 4.1.1 , em algumas distribuições base debian, com esse comando  tras a versão anterior a 3.6 onde limita o uso de muitos pacotes.

No meu caso, o uso desses comandos com minha atual distro vem 4.0, mas não quero esta, E sim 4.1.1 

mas muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a informação disponível na [página de download do programa](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/), a versão mais atual está disponível no repositório do Debian **Sid**, que você pode adicionar de forma segura ao seu sistema, [usando uma configuração de baixa prioridade do `apt`](https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration#apt_preferences_.28APT_pinning.29), para que nenhum pacote não desejado seja instalado por acidente.

Você pode instalar esse programa na sua distribuição com os seguintes comandos:

Primeiro a adição do arquivo de *pinning* que define a *baixa prioridade* aos pacotes desse repositório, impedindo que eles se sobreponham aos pacotes do repositório principal da sua distribuição:

```
cat <<EOF |sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/sid
# Sid
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 100
EOF
```

Em seguida a adição do endereço do repositório:

```
echo 'deb https://deb.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free'|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-sid.list
```

Agora o download da chave de acesso:

Download com o `aria2`:

```
aria2c --console-log-level=error --summary-interval=0 -o debian-keyring.deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-keyring/debian-keyring_2021.09.25_all.deb
```

Download com o `curl`:

```
curl -sLo debian-keyring.deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-keyring/debian-keyring_2021.09.25_all.deb
```

Download com o `wget`:

```
 wget -qO debian-keyring.deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-keyring/debian-keyring_2021.09.25_all.deb
```

Instalação da chave:

```
sudo apt install ./debian-keyring.deb
sudo apt update
```

E por fim a instalação do programa:

```
sudo apt install -t=sid r-base
```